# PHP Unexplainable Error, Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I can't find a mistake in my code, and I always get the following error:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' "

when trying to submit some inputs from a form.

```
if (isset($_GET['createNewBox'])) {

  if (!empty($_POST['tableName']) and !empty($_POST['commentFullAddress'])) {

    try{

        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE :tableName (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            customerid INT,
            item TEXT,
            pin INT(11) NOT NULL,
            position VARCHAR(5),
            storedate DATE NOT NULL,
            storetime TIME NOT NULL
            ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=INNODB COMMENT=":commentFullAddress"';
        $statement = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
        $statement -> bindValue(':tableName', $_POST['tableName']);
        $statement -> bindValue(':commentFullAddress', $_POST['commentFullAddress']);

        if ($statement -> execute()) {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['messageSucceed'] = "A new database has been created for the box.";
            header('Location: /?managebox');
            exit();
        }   

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        $error_output = "Error on creating new box database: " . $e;
        include '../error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

  } else {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Please do not submit empty data.";
    header("Location: /?managebox");
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `":commentFullAddress"`, otherwise it will denote the literal string `:commentFullAddress` instead of a parameter name.

Comment: PDO treat your values as its needed. `:commentFullAddress` will be wrapped with quotes automatically. If you wrap manually with quotes it will be treated as a literal string, as @Siguza said

Comment: I have removed the quotes around the :commentFullAddress, but now, I got this error "Error on creating new box database: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''box3' ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, customerid INT' at line 1'"


I put the quote around the :commentFullAddress because I thought the quote was needed to be there for the COMMENT in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your code.

Firstly, this:

```
CREATE TABLE :tableName
```

You can't bind a table in PDO, so you need to either use a variable or from a safelist.

Then you're using quotes around the values for the binds `COMMENT=":commentFullAddress"';` and those need to be removed.

**Sidenote:** TBH, I don't know why you're using a prepared statement for the COMMENT, I've never seen that before.

References:

- [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)
- [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Plus, make sure those POST arrays contain values.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

You also may have to change `bindValue` to `bindParam`, I said "may".

---

**Footnotes:**

I don't understand why you're using this code to create a table, yet alone coming from user input. That's your decision but I don't see the reason for it, unless you're trying to create some form of database hosting service.

Comment: I have made some changes according to your suggestion, but I still get the same error "number of bound variables does not match number of tokens".
`code`
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customerid INT,
    item TEXT,
    pin INT(11) NOT NULL,
    position VARCHAR(5),
    storedate DATE NOT NULL,
    storetime TIME NOT NULL
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=INNODB COMMENT=:commentFullAddress";`
`code`

Comment: @DarkSpirit My guess is that MySQL probably won't let you create a COMMENT from a prepared statement. TBH, I've never seen that before, so try removing it entirely. Plus, did you remove `$statement -> bindValue(':tableName', $_POST['tableName']);` ?

Comment: @DarkSpirit Plus, you are connecting with PDO right and not MySQLi_ or MySQL_?

Comment: I did forget to remove the bindValue(':tableName', $_POST['tableName']). My code is working fine now :) Yes, I am connecting with PDO. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DarkSpirit That's great, glad to hear it, *cheers and you're welcome!*